# Celery - избыточный запуск задач

Tags: python, cron, celery

Имеем периодическую задачу `celery`

```
@periodic_task(run_every=crontab(hour=6))
def task():
    pass
```

Запускаем данную задачу каждое утро в 6 часов утра. Запуск задачи логгируем.

Прошло ПАРУ дней, ожидаем в логах увидеть ДВЕ строчки.

Но `celery` запускало данную задачу раз 20. Обвесили кучей логгеров, прикрутили `sentry`, упростили задачу до минимума, но задача продолжает запускаться не так, как нужно.

В чем может быть проблема?

Ожидаемое поведение описал.

Команда для запуска воркера:

`celery -A project worker -B --loglevel=info --logfile=./logs/celery.log`

Comment: Воркер точно запущен ровно один раз?

Comment: @andreymal да. Одинаковое поведение как на локалке, так и на проде (используем docker). Без докера на локалке та же беда.

Comment: Так стоп, если я правильно понимаю документацию, crontab по умолчанию настроен на каждую минуту - попробуйте явно прописать минуты в ноль

Comment: @andreymal если это было бы так, то задачка запускалась бы каждую минуту. А у нас как-будто бы запускается пачка задачек, вместо двух. Как будто в очереди задач есть еще такие задачи. Также пробовали на локалке запускать каждую 38, 40, 45 минуту и тд для дебага - тоже не очевидное поведение.

Comment: Тогда догадки пока что кончились, лично у меня celery работает нормально. Тем не менее пропишите в тексте вопроса минуту явно, чтобы не было лишних вопросов от других пользователей

Comment: @andreymal в любом случае спасибо. Возможно, мы что-то не так поняли.

Answer (score 0):

Решение:

```
@periodic_task(run_every=crontab(hour=6, minute=0))
def task():
    pass
```

(Добавлено `minute=0`).

Прощу прощения у `@andreymal` т.к. проверили его теорию в деле только сейчас. Были уверены, что если бы проблема была в минуте, задачи бы запускались каждую минуту.

Вообщем, странное поведение решилось именно так, как нам и было посоветовано попробовать - добавить `minute=0`.